# Show that a Matrix Group is a Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^k \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m \geq 1$, that is
$P(\lambda x) = \lambda^m P(x), \lambda \in \mathbb{R},x \in \mathbb{R}^k$.

Prove that $<\nabla f(x), x>= mf(x)$.

Show that $y \neq 0$ is a regular value of $f$.

Use this to conclude that matrix group $SL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}): \text{det}(A) = 1\}$ is a manifold.

EDIT:

Okay, Here's my attempt at a solution. Although I am not certain that I used y as it was intended and am in general uncertain about what I have done.

But I'll post my solution in case anyone needs something similar, or is able to improve upon what I have done.

a.)Prove that $<∇f(x),x>=mf(x)$

Let $g(\lambda)=f(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, ..., \lambda x_k)= \lambda^m f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$.

Differentiating, using the chain rule,

$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\lambda x) x_i = m \lambda^{m-1} f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$

Choose $\lambda = 1$.

Therefore, $ \hspace{0.1 cm} <\nabla f(x), x> = m f(x)$.

b.)Show that $y≠0$ is a regular value of $f$.

Let $f$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m \geqslant 1$ and $ y \neq 0$. Let $x \in f^{-1}(y)$.

So, using (a.) we obtain

$<\nabla f(x), x> = m f(y) \neq 0$

Which implies that $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$, so $Df(x): \mathbb{R}^k \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is surjective $\forall$ $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Therefore, $y \neq 0$ is a regular value.

c.) 
The group $SL_n(R) \subset M_n(R) = \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is equal to $f^{-1}(1)$ where $f(A) = det(A)$.

Now, $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so $1$ is a regular value of $f$, by (b.)

So, $SL_n(R) = f^{-1}(1)$ is a differentiable manifold of degree $n^2 -1$.

Comment: Please include your attempts and specific challenges.  Also, you haven't explained what $y$ is.

Comment: This is (almost) a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1357681/sln-is-a-differentiable-manifold), or [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385410/problems-on-submanifolds).

Comment: Sorry, the question I was given does not explain what $y$ is, it just states "show that $ y \neq 0$ is a regular value of $f$".

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Here's my attempt at a solution. Although I am not certain that I used y as it was intended and am in general uncertain about what I have done.

But I'll post my solution in case anyone needs something similar, or is able to improve upon what I have done.

a.)Prove that $<∇f(x),x>=mf(x)$

Let $g(\lambda)=f(\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2, ..., \lambda x_k)= \lambda^m f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$.

Differentiating, using the chain rule,

$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(\lambda x) x_i = m \lambda^{m-1} f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)$

Choose $\lambda = 1$.

Therefore, $ \hspace{0.1 cm} <\nabla f(x), x> = m f(x)$.

b.)Show that $y≠0$ is a regular value of $f$.

Let $f$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $m \geqslant 1$ and $ y \neq 0$. Let $x \in f^{-1}(y)$.

So, using (a.) we obtain

$<\nabla f(x), x> = m f(y) \neq 0$

Which implies that $\nabla f(x) \neq 0$, so $Df(x): \mathbb{R}^k \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is surjective $\forall$ $x \in f^{-1}(y)$. Therefore, $y \neq 0$ is a regular value.

c.) 
The group $SL_n(R) \subset M_n(R) = \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ is equal to $f^{-1}(1)$ where $f(A) = det(A)$.

Now, $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, so $1$ is a regular value of $f$, by (b.)

So, $SL_n(R) = f^{-1}(1)$ is a differentiable manifold of degree $n^2 -1$.

EDIT:

I have since updated my post to include my attempt at an answer in it.